# Order Most Similar Values Together in List

Tags: python, python-3.x

Lets say I have six instruments that I can program on my synth, as follows:

```
patches = {
  "piano":        (0,  10, 20, 30, 50), 
  "grand-piano":  (10, 10, 20, 35, 45),
  "guitar":       (80, 0,  50, 33, 80),
  "trumpet":      (85, 85, 85, 90, 90),
  "banjo":        (95, 0,  60, 45, 75),
  "trombone":     (95, 85, 85, 90, 85),
}
```

where each instrument is defined using a unique set of five parameter values. So the piano sound is produced by programming the synth with the values: `0, 10, 20, 30, 50`.

I'd like to order the list of patches so that the most similar instruments get sorted together. You can see that the piano and grand-piano are very similar, so they should end up together. If you add the differences in parameter values for these two instruments you get:

`10+0+0+5+5=20`

which is what I mean by close. Likewise the guitar and banjo are close, as are the trumpet and trombone.

I can establish how similar each instrument is to each other instrument as follows:

```
from itertools import combinations

def distance(a,b):
    assert len(a) == len(b)
    return sum(abs(a[i]-b[i]) for i in range(len(a)))

distances = { (a,b): distance(patches[a], patches[b]) for a,b in combinations(patches.keys(),r=2) }
```

But I'm not sure how to order a list with the patches based on this information. How might I proceed?

**UPDATE**

I think this is the solution based on Александр Слабкин's implementation:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors as NN
from sklearn.neighbors import DistanceMetric as DM
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize


patches = {
           "piano":        (0,  10, 20, 30, 50),
           "grand-piano":  (10, 10, 20, 35, 45),
           "guitar":       (80, 0,  50, 33, 80),
           "trumpet":      (85, 85, 85, 90, 90),
           "banjo":        (95, 0,  60, 45, 75),
           "trombone":     (95, 85, 85, 90, 85),
}

dist = DM.get_metric('manhattan')

patches = list(patches.items())
n = len(patches)

l = [i[1] for i in patches]

neighbors = NN(n).fit(l)
distances, indices = neighbors.kneighbors(l)

best_indices = sorted(((indices[i], sum(distances[i])) for i in range(len(indices))),key=lambda x:x[1])[0][0]
print([patches[i][0] for i in best_indices])
```

Comment: What you want is known as "clustering".  There are many good algorithms that do this.

Comment: Your objective function isn't very clear. Points in 5 dimensional space don't line up nicely, so I'm not sure that it is useful to think of this as a type of sorting. If all you have is 6, you could brute-force it easily enough, as soon as you have a good way to judge between two possible permutations.

Comment: @John Coleman Order might be a better word than Sort.

Comment: So, in your algorithm, two instruments are closed when their differences are `<= 20`. Is it correct ? If it is correct, thus guitar and banjo are not closed as you state in your post. Surely, you have an objective function problem. Check it out!

Comment: If you want an ordering of the list which minimises the distance between consecutive elements, this is the Travelling Salesman Problem, in disguise: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem

Answer (score 1):

It's not that simple. You have many dimensions. And there is no reference point (the ideal instrument) from which to compare everything else. However, if convert to an array you can find all the distances and sort them with `sklearn.neighbors`.

---

```
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors as NN
from sklearn.neighbors import DistanceMetric as DM
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize


patches = {
           "piano":        (0,  10, 20, 30, 50),
           "grand-piano":  (10, 10, 20, 35, 45),
           "guitar":       (80, 0,  50, 33, 80),
           "trumpet":      (85, 85, 85, 90, 90),
           "banjo":        (95, 0,  60, 45, 75),
           "trombone":     (95, 85, 85, 90, 85),
}

dist = DM.get_metric('euclidean')

n = len(patches)
l = list(patches.values())
l = normalize(l)
distances1 = dist.pairwise(l)
print(distances1) # distances from each to each other

neighbors = NN(n).fit(l)
distances, indices = neighbors.kneighbors(l)


print(distances) # same as distances1 but sorted
print(indices)
```

Output:

```
[[0.         0.19664399 0.70818726 0.62892825 0.76357009 0.67486123]
 [0.19664399 0.         0.5912477  0.49435355 0.62671507 0.5346901 ]
 [0.70818726 0.5912477  0.         0.54458768 0.1255816  0.53411468]
 [0.62892825 0.49435355 0.54458768 0.         0.51928639 0.05581397]
 [0.76357009 0.62671507 0.1255816  0.51928639 0.         0.49940661]
 [0.67486123 0.5346901  0.53411468 0.05581397 0.49940661 0.        ]]


[[0.         0.19664399 0.62892825 0.67486123 0.70818726 0.76357009]
 [0.         0.19664399 0.49435355 0.5346901  0.5912477  0.62671507]
 [0.         0.1255816  0.53411468 0.54458768 0.5912477  0.70818726]
 [0.         0.05581397 0.49435355 0.51928639 0.54458768 0.62892825]
 [0.         0.1255816  0.49940661 0.51928639 0.62671507 0.76357009]
 [0.         0.05581397 0.49940661 0.53411468 0.5346901  0.67486123]]

[[0 1 3 5 2 4]
 [1 0 3 5 2 4]
 [2 4 5 3 1 0]
 [3 5 1 4 2 0]
 [4 2 5 3 1 0]
 [5 3 4 2 1 0]]
```

In the first nested list of `indices` (third `print`) we received all instruments (their indexes) sorted by distance to the first instrument. And so on.

Comment: Thanks fo your answer. Why does the euclidean metric result in the piano being closer to the trumpet (0.62892825) than the guitar (0.70818726)?

Comment: I think "manhattan" should be used instead of euclidean.

Comment: To be honest, I didn't check the calculations, but the sklearn library is quite reliable. So most likely the piano is really closer to the trumpet with Euclidean metric. Yeah, manhattan might be better for this particular task. You should add it here: neighbors = NN(n, metric='manhattan').fit(l). And You can delete dist = DM.get_metric('manhattan'). It was more for illustration.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution I wrote up:

```
patches = {
    "piano":        (0,  10, 20, 30, 50), 
    "grand-piano":  (10, 10, 20, 35, 45),
    "guitar":       (80, 0,  50, 33, 80),
    "trumpet":      (85, 85, 85, 90, 90),
    "banjo":        (95, 0,  60, 45, 75),
    "trombone":     (95, 85, 85, 90, 85),
}

import functools
import copy

maxI = [float("inf"), []]

# Returns the difference between two arrays
def return_diff(l1, l2):
    total = []
    for i in range(len(l1)):
        # Arrange the array then reduce it
        total.append(functools.reduce(lambda x, y: y-x, sorted([l1[i], l2[i]])))
    return functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, total)

# 2D looping to order by closest affinity
for i, j in patches.items():
    print(i, end=" ")
    maxI = [float("inf"), []]
    for k, l in patches.items():
        diff = [return_diff(l, j), k]
        if maxI[0] > diff[0] and diff[0] != 0:
            maxI = copy.deepcopy(diff)
    print(maxI)
```

I'm assuming you want to order them by finding the difference then reducing them. Basically, for every item, the program loops over the object again to filters out the bigger values. maxI is set to a lower value each time and isn't changed if the value is bigger thus finding the smallest value.